# How to desugar a yield from syntax in Python?

Tags: python, yield-from

Now I'm studying on the differences between a yield-from and an await syntax. From the official python documentation, the yield-from generator() is just a syntax suger of the following code:

```py
for i in generator(): yield i
```

But I can't desugar the yield-from in the example below.

```py
def accumlate():
    # context
    accumlator = 0
    while True:
        next = yield
        if next is None:
            return accumlator
        accumlator += next


def gather(tallies):
    while True:
        tally = yield from accumlate() # (*)
        tallies.append(tally)

def main():
    tallies = []
    accumlator = gather(tallies)
    next(accumlator)
    for i in range(4):
        accumlator.send(i)

    accumlator.send(None)
    for i in range(6, 10):
        accumlator.send(i)
    accumlator.send(None)
    print(tallies)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried to just replace a yield-from with the for-in version, but it did't work because the for-in can't be placed on the right side of the tally variable. What is an exact desugar of the code marked with asterisk ?

Answer (score 1):

@DerteTrdelnik's answer is largely correct, except that you don't have to modify the `accumlate` function at all, since a generator would already automatically raise `StopIteration` with the returning value as a parameter to construct the exception object when the generator returns without a yield.

Excerpt from the documentation of [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration):

> When a generator or coroutine function returns, a new `StopIteration`
>   instance is raised, and the `value` returned by the function is used as
>   the value parameter to the constructor of the exception.

Therefore, you only need to "desugar" the `gather` function as such:

```
def gather(tallies):
    while True:
        a = accumlate()
        a.send(None)
        while True:
            try:
                a.send((yield))
            except StopIteration as e:
                tallies.append(e.value)
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

`result = yield from generator()` is not easily substituted, it is the way of how to get to the return value of generator

see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#proposal

to simulate a bit of what is going on without using yield from we have to modify both of the generators

```
def accumlate():
    # context
    accumlator = 0
    while True:
        next = yield
        if next is None:
            raise StopIteration(accumlator)
        accumlator += next


def gather(tallies):
    internal_acc = accumlate()
    internal_acc.send(None)
    while True:
        try:
            number_to_add = yield
            internal_acc.send(number_to_add)
        except StopIteration as e:
            internal_acc = accumlate()
            internal_acc.send(None)
            tallies.append(e.value)
```

`accumlate` is no longer returning, but raising and `gather` has to try except that raise,

after `internal_acc` is exhausted a new one is created in the except

there is a bit more to it as seen in the pep0380, but basically generator return is a raise and yield from is a compact catch for that